# CSS positioning problem

Tags: html, css

I have some html that is inserted dynamically with javascript. I have `position:absolute;` so that it does not affect the layout of the page elements. However, when a flash message appears on the top of the page, all of the elements shift down except for the absolutely positioned element. So it seems that I want to combine properties of absolute and relative positioning. How do I do this?

Comment: show some code for a better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position:relative;` to the highest-level element which you think describes "the page". For example:

```
<body>
    <div id="popup>
        <!-- "flash" popup message is inserted into DOM here -->
    </div>
    <div id="main content" style="position:relative;"><!--THIS IS "THE PAGE"-->
        ...
            ...
                <!-- your "absolutely" positioned element -->
            ...
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

**edit**: This is an excellent demo by thirtydot which perfectly illustrates the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/qGTw6

Comment: This is a better answer. Here's the demo I just finished making showing the same idea: http://jsfiddle.net/qGTw6/

Comment: @user730569: that is not what I meant; you should never add styles to the HTML tag. see example

Comment: @thirtydot: very nice demo that perfectly illustrates the concept

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative` to a parent element of your absolutely positioned element.

Make sure your "flash message" is outside this element.

Comment: See the demo I posted in a comment on @ninjagecko's answer.

Comment: adding `position:relative;` to body should have no effect on anything... (maybe some quirky behavior)

Comment: @ninjagecko: Just for your info, that last comment of yours wasn't fully correct. Try removing `position: relative` here: http://jsfiddle.net/7rU6M/